# call Controller function from Model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, controller

I need to use Controller's `Server.MapPath` method to get the path for the app data to access them from a model class. So if i create this function in HomeController:

```
public string getPathls()
{
    string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Folder/");
    return path;
}
```

how can I call it from a model class like this:

```
string pathi = Project.Controllers.HomeController....//what next?
```

Comment: A model class should not access control methods. Create a utility class or something like that where model and controller can get this information from

Comment: are there any tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: If you really need to do this, I'd recommend passing the path to the model from the controller. `var model = new MyModel(HttpContext.Server.MapPath(...));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it Wooooorks! I can call it from Model and it gets the path

```
var pathi = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Temps/file.xml");

            string ff = pathi.ToString();
```